# RGBDSlam load saved files

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to load the saved PCD file to rgbdslam for later use? What I am trying to do is create a map, and then later come along and locate my position/orientation within the map.

Update:
I am able to load a pointcloud into a pointcloud_type for use in rgbdslam but I'm not sure how or where to add it to the graph. I have a call to setPointCloud(cloud, transform) but it isn't working correctly, as it was a shot in the dark. Below is a snippit of code, this method is set up in graph_manager.cpp, and is called from qtcv when the menu option is clicked and a file is selected. I know that it is correctly loading the file because the ROS_INFO call works and says that it is loading points.

```
void GraphManager::loadCloudsFromFile(QString filename){
     string * printableFileName = new string(qPrintable(filename));
     pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
     if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(*printableFileName, *cloud) == -1)
     {
         ROS_ERROR("Couldn't read file %s", printableFileName->c_str());
         return;
     }
     ROS_INFO("Loaded %d, data points from %s", cloud->width * cloud->height, printableFileName->c_str());
     pointcloud_type * cloud2 = new pointcloud_type(*cloud);
     //sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud2;
     //pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud, cloud2);
     latest_transform_ = QMatrix4x4();
     Q_EMIT(setPointCloud(cloud2, latest_transform_));
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11855/rgbdslam-load-saved-files/) by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lguodongustc](https://answers.ros.org/users/10416/lguodongustc/) on 2014-05-15**:
Hi , I want to fuse the RGBD-SLAM to multi-robots, and i have the similar problem,  have you implemented it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
this isn't possible with RGBDSLAM at the moment (and I currently have no plans to add this feature). To implement this, in addition to the point cloud, you would also need to store the belonging feature descriptors and their 2d/3d locations. Further the graph would need to be saved (there is a function for that in hogman/g2o).

So in fact, one would need to implent saving and restoring of the Node class.

While the principle is easy, this would be a lot of programming work, and since I don't have time for it, I guess it will not be done. Anyone willing to volunteer is welcome to contact me for details.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-11-18**:
Yes, sure. Since this board is only for questions, I'll answer your email.

**Comment by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on 2011-11-18**:
I would be interested in taking a look at the work required, would you care to help me going about doing this? I've been working with RGBDSlam but don't know how things exactly work, but I do have a rough idea.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question was already addressed under [how to save a point cloud](http://answers.ros.org/question/2785/how-to-save-a-point-cloud).

The [pcd_to_pointcloud](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros#pcd_to_pointcloud) node from the [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) package can publish data previously saved in a PCD.

If you need more details or examples, please post another comment.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-11**:
I can't help you with the internals of RGBDSlam. Maybe one of those developers will answer.

**Comment by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on 2011-11-11**:
Thanks for the udpate. Maybe I'm missing something but I'm not sure how this helps since I already have a point cloud inside a function I added to RGBDSlam. The function is in graph_manager.cpp now I need to add it to the graph, but idk how. Do I add it to optimizer_ or graph_? How?

**Comment by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on 2011-11-10**:
Ok, now I can successfully load the file, but how do I get that data into rgbdslam so I can continue creating the map? I vaguely understand how rgbdslam works under the hood and I'm not sure how to add the point cloud back in.